# Как запретить доступ в инет своей программе?

Tags: c++

Использую стороннюю библиотеку, из которой периодически идёт обращение на их сервер с целью обновления. Как запретить? СВОЕЙ ПРОГРАММЕ любой доступ в инет?

Comment: С целью обновления? Это чтобы обновиться и сломать уже устовленую программу?) Я встречал похожее, и там либы ходили в интернет проверить лицензию...

Comment: Если библиотека не в исходниках, то, скорее всего, никак. Или грязные хаки с бинарной отладкой и коррекцией кода. А если по-простому, то наверное можно найти в бинарнике библиотеки строку с именем их сервера и переправить ее на 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Как называется библиотека? Мануал смотрели, может это как-то отключается?

Comment: В любой операционной системе есть сетевой экран (он же файерволл), который как раз и предназначен для ограничения доступа программ в сеть. Поищите в интернете, как на вашей операционной системе настроить полный запрет для программы с конкретным именем или путём.

Comment: "Это чтобы обновиться и сломать уже установленную программу?" Именно так. каждые два месяца прога вылетает и просит обновиться